# Event Store DB : temporal queries

Tags: eventstoredb

regarding to asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63794162/querying-eventstoredb-with-java-api-or-http-api) :

suppose that we have ProductCreated and ProductRenamed events which both contain the title of the product.now we want to query EventStoreDB for all events of type ProductCreated and ProductRenamed with the given title.i want all these events to check whether there is any product in the system which has been created or renamed to the given title, so that i could throw the exception of repetitive title in the domain

i am using MongoDB for creating UI reports from all the published events and everything is fine there.but for checking some invariants, like checking for unique values, i have to either query the event store for some events along with their criteria and by iterating over them, decide whether there is a product created with the same title which has not renamed or a product renamed with the same title.

for such queries, the only way that event store provides is creating a one-time projection with the proper java script code which filters and emits required events to a new stream.and then all i have to do is to fetch events from the new generated stream which is filled by the projection

no the odd thing is, projections are great for subscriptions and generating new streams, but they seem to be odd for doing real time queries.immediately after i create a projection with the HTTP api, i check the new resulting stream for the query result, but it seems that the workers has not got the chance to elaborate on the result and i get 404 response.but after waiting for a bunch of seconds, the new streams pops out and gets filled with the result.

there are too many things wrong with this approach:

first, it seems that if the event store is filled with millions of events across many streams, it wont be able to process and filter all of them immediately to the resulting stream.it does not create the stream immediately, let alone the population.so i have to wait for some time and check for the result hoping the the projection is done

second, i have to fetch multiple times and issue multiple GET HTTP commands which seems to be slow.the new JVM client is not ready yet.

Third, i have to delete the resulting stream after i'm done with the result and failing to do so will leave event store with millions of orphan query result streams

i wish i could pass the java script to some api and get the result page by page like querying MongoDB without worrying about the projection, new streams and timing issues.

i have seen a query section in the Admin UI, but i dont know whats that for, and unfortunetly the documentation doesn't help much

am i expecting the event store to do something that is impossible?
do i have to create a bounded context inner read model for doing such checks?

i am using my events to dehyderate the aggregates and willing to use the same events for such simple queries without acquiring other techniques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would not be a separate bounded context since the check you want to perform belongs to the same bounded context where your Product aggregate lives. So, the projection that is solely used to prevent duplicate product names would be a part of the same context.

You can indeed use a custom projection to check it but I believe the complexity of such a solution would be higher than having a simple read model in MongoDB.

It is also fine to use an existing projection if you have one to do the check. It might be not what you would otherwise prefer if the aim of the existing projection is to show things in the UI.

For the collection that you could use for duplicates check, you can have the document schema limited to the id only (string), which would be the product title. Since collections are automatically indexed by the id, you won't need any additional indexes to support the duplicate check query. When the product gets renamed, you'd need to delete the document for the old title and add a new one.

Again, you will get a small time window when the duplicate can slip in. It's then up to the business to decide if the concern is real (it's not, most of the time) and what's the consequence of the situation if it happens one day. You'd be able to find a duplicate when projecting events quite easily and decide what to do when it happens.

Practically, when you have such a projection, all it takes is to build a simple domain service `bool ProductTitleAlreadyExists`.

Comment: checking for a product with unique title,was an example to show if we could query the event store db.and with your description i came to conclusion that it is not possible to query event store db, the way we know and exprience querying from others.and projections are not equivalant to query, at least not in the way how they deliver the result.there are fairy simple queries that are constructed with checking simple criteria over some events and realized that i should use another write model inside my BC to do that.i wish i could query against event store db the way i query MongoDB.thanks anyway

Comment: Well, let's make things clear. If we talk about temporal queries, there should be a concept of time involved. Like "this happened and in 5 min something else happened". When it comes to queries, I believe it's important to understand that querying events is very much different from querying the state. Although you can write an ad-hoc projection for a query, it's not the main use case that you'd use in your applications. https://eventstore.com/blog/projections-4-event-matching/